# How to enable and disable sort in Yii2 GridView?

Tags: sorting, gridview, yii2

**How to enable and disable sort in Yii2 GridView ?**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can customize columns sort in your `DataProvider`. For example if you use `ActiveDataProvider` in your `GridView` you can indicate sort-able columns like below:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Model::find(),
    'sort' => ['attributes' => ['column1','column2']]
]);
```

In above example, only `column1` and `column2` are sort-able.

You can also disable sorting for all columns like below:

```
'sort' =>false
```

It is suggested to take a look at `Yii2`'s official document : [**Class yii\data\Sort**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html) As it defines it:

> **Sort represents information relevant to sorting.**
>   When data needs to be sorted according to one or several attributes, we can use Sort to represent the sorting information and generate appropriate hyperlinks that can lead to sort actions.

Comment: How can I sort relational and aggregation data?

Comment: I've not found a way of making this work in a scenario where you wish to apply a sort to an ActiveDataProvider but then not allow the user to re-sort. For such a scenario, you can apply @Priyanka's solution.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Ali's answer, for aggregated and related columns you could do the following:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => User::find()->joinWith('role'),
          'sort' => ['attributes' => [
                   //Normal columns
                   'username',
                   'email',
                   //aggregated columns
                   'full_name' => [
                        'asc' => ['first_name' => SORT_ASC, 'last_name' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['first_name' => SORT_DESC, 'last_name' => SORT_DESC],
                        'default' => SORT_DESC
                   ],
                   //related columns
                   'role.name' => [
                        'asc' => ['user_role.name' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['user_role.name' => SORT_DESC],
                        'default' => SORT_DESC
                   ],
              ],],
    ]);
}
```

**Source:** http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html

Comment: Hello! Could you please tell me how do sorting for double relation? E.g `location.city.name`

Answer (score 18):

If you want disable sorting from gridview for particular column then do like this:

```
 [
     'attribute' => 'name',
     'enableSorting' => false
 ],
```

by using `'enableSorting' => false`

Comment: This also works when you wish to apply a sort to an ActiveDataProvider but then not allow the user to re-sort. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You can disable sort in controller like this:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->sort->sortParam = false;
```

Comment: $dataProvider->sort = false; to disable all sort field